# RAILS: Access other path helpers after routing into mounted class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, forem

Say I'm integrating `forem` into my apps, and my `routes.rb` seems like this:

```
# items
resources :items, only: [:index, :show]

# forem
mount Forem::Engine, :at => '/forums'
```

And In my default layout `layout/Application.erb.html`, there's something like:

```
link_to 'items', items_path
```

and, in `/forums` pages, it occurs that:

```
undefined local variable or method `items_path'
```

so, how can I access other path helpers after routing into mounted class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add main_app in front of the path like this:

```
link_to 'items', main_app.items_path
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind guys, pls check this:

https://github.com/radar/forem/wiki/Installing---Upgrading#application-route-helpers